# Binary number system that can survive rotations?

Tags: binary, binary-data

I need to encode data within a data stream where the bits of each integer can be arbitrarily rotated. For example, with a 4-bit integer:

```
0000 0

0001 1
0010 1
0100 1
1000 1

0011 2
0110 2
1100 2
1001 2

0101 3
1010 3

0111 4
1110 4
1101 4
1011 4

1111 5
```

1000, 0100, 0010 and 0001 are equal to the same number because they are rotated versions of each other. Similarly, 1100, 0110, 0011, 1001 are the same number. 0101 and 1010 are the same number but are different from 1100.

Counting on-bits is close, but is not optimal because 1100 can be distinguished from 1010.

Is there a well recognized/understood binary numbering system that can represent this?